# smbldap-useradd: what are the different addresses for?

Tags: samba, ldap, openldap

`smbldap-useradd` has some parameters to specify addresses for the user:

```
# smbldap-useradd  --help | grep -i addr
  -M    e-mail address (comma separated)
  -O    localMailAddress (comma separated)
  -T    mailToAddress (forward address) (comma separated)
```

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error messages given by `smbldap-useradd` when using the parameters, I'd say:

`-M` preferred email addresses (e.g. name.surname@work.com)
`-O` email aliases (e.g. name@work.com, manager@work.com)
`-T` final mailbox destinations (e.g. user001@work.com)